# C - Linked list next node is null

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to obtain the next value of my struct by using a linked list but the next value is null.

I know that I'm not doing this the right way, hope you can help me to solve my problem.

Input file:

```
new_employee Hasselhoff David PDG F-13000 1 
new_employee Anderson Pamela DDR F-31000 2 
new_employee LeeNolin Gena DDR F-94270 3
new_employee Charvet David DPR F-54000 4
```

The code:

```
char    *my_strcat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
  char  *tmp;
  int   i;
  int   j;

  i = -1;
  j = 0;
  tmp = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(s1) + strlen(s2)) + 1);
  while (s1[++i])
    tmp[j++] = s1[i];
  i = -1;
  while (s2[++i])
    tmp[j++] = s2[i];
  tmp[j] = '\0';
  return (tmp);
}

char    *read_func()
{
  char *str;
  char line[256];

  str = malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin))
    str = my_strcat(str, line);
  return (str);
}

void            fill_struct(t_emp *s_emp)
{
  char          *read;

  read = read_func();
  if (strstr(read, "new_employee"))
    {
      while (s_emp->next != NULL)
        s_emp = s_emp->next;
      s_emp->next = malloc(sizeof(t_emp));
      strdup(strtok(read, " "));
      s_emp->name = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));
      s_emp->forename = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));
      s_emp->job = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));
      s_emp->zipcode = strdup(strtok(NULL, " "));
      s_emp->id = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
      s_emp = s_emp->next;
    }
}

void    print_emp(t_emp *s_emp)
{
  while (s_emp != NULL)
    {
      printf("******************************\n");
      printf("%s %s\n", s_emp->forename, s_emp->name);
      printf("position: %s\n", s_emp->job);
      printf("city: %s\n", s_emp->zipcode);
      s_emp = s_emp->next;
    }
}
```

main function:

```
int     main()
{
  t_emp s_emp;

  if (!isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
    {
      fill_struct(&s_emp);
      print_emp(&s_emp);
    }
  else
    show_help();
}
```

output:

```
******************************
David Hasselhoff
position: PDG
city: F-13000
******************************
(null) (null)
position: (null)
city: (null)
```

desired output:

```
******************************
David Hasselhoff
position: PDG
city: F-13000
******************************
Pamela Anderson
position: DDR
city: F-31000
```

Thanks!

Comment: You do `s_emp->next = malloc(..` and then you assign the values to `emp`. You should assign to `emp->next`, the new node.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that because I don't really get it at the moment?

Comment: No @PaulOgilvie, he is actually just allocating beforehand. He is populating correctly

Comment: You do `strdup(strtok(read, " "));` but don't use the string returned by `strdup`. You leak memory.

Comment: I have to use strcpy() instead?

Comment: Please show the whole program and how `fill_struct` is called.

Comment: `s_emp = s_emp->next;` in `fill_struct` has no use. You can remove the line. What do you want to do?

Comment: I've edited the post, and I want to make a linked list with all the "new_employees" record and then print it.

Comment: 1) You need loop. 2) Initialize before use.

Comment: Well, your `read_func` reads all of the lines of the file into a single buffer, but your `fill_struct` only processes the first. Then your `print_emp` also prints the last entry of the list, which is empty. I suggest you loop over the input, adding a record for each line read.

Comment: Alright, I understand. So basically I need to do my linked list in my read_func() ? I tried to loop over my input but it's giving me a SEGFAULT...

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/2Pk3YK)

Comment: Is it because the reason to concatenate inputs is not one line per record?

Comment: Thank you very much @BLUEPIXY

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `fill_struct` in a loop; the `if` statement will only run once, and it will stop after the first employee.  The best way to do this is simply modifying the `if` statement in that function to a `while` one.  For example:

```
//...
while (strstr(read, "new_employee") != NULL)
//...
```

Leveraging the fact that [`strstr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) will return NULL if the next occurrence of "new_employee" is not found.

As the comments have pointed out, your first `s_emp = s_emp->next` in the `while` loop is unnecessary as it will *always* be `NULL`; you don't assign `s_emp->next` until the next line.

Furthermore, your first call to [`strdup`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) is not valid as you must `free` the pointer returned from that call.  So store it in a variable and free it later.

Aside: why is your `my_strcat` function so complicated?  `strcat` is simply the equivalent of this:

```
char *p = str1;

while (*p) //Traverse to the end of str1 
  p++;
while (*p++ = *str2++) //Will stop with copying '\0' over
  ;

return str1;
```

It need not be more complicated than that.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that. And I learned to do the my_strcat that way, but thank you for the tip, I appreciate.

Comment: @ArnaudPradier Condensing your implementation of `strcat` was simply a suggestion as it seemed a little cluttered.  I'm glad it helped a bit!